# Problem with Django url

Tags: django, django-urls

Going to http://127.0.0.1:8300/projects/cprshelp/edit_file/?filename=manage.py results in a 404 error

urls.py

```
(r'^projects/(?P<project_name>[\w ,-<>]+)/', include('projects.urls')),
```

projects/urls.py

```
(r'edit_file/$', views.edit_file),
```

What do I need to change to my url files to make this particular url work?

List of valid urls:

```
^admin/doc/
^admin/
^projects/(?P<project_name>[\w ,-<>]+)/ edit_file/$
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
```

edit_file function:

```
def edit_file(request, project_name):
    print '**** project name ' + project_name
    #project = Project.objects.get(name=project_name)

    filename = request.GET['filename']
    #content_of_file = open(project.file_location + filename, 'r')
    #content_of_file = '\n'.join(content_of_file.readlines())

    context = RequestContext(request, {
        #"project": project,
        #"files": get_files_and_directories(project.file_location),
        "filename": filename,
        #"content_of_file": content_of_file,
    })        

    return render_to_response("edit_file.html", context)
```

Comment: Is it an actual 404 or does it tell you that this is an invalid url and give you a list of valid URLs? If the latter, can you post the URLs that it gives?

Comment: show your edit_file view

Comment: See edited problem description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to backslash your `-` in your regex:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'projects/[\w ,-<>]+/')>>> p.search('http://127.0.0.1:8300/projects/cprshelp/edit_file/?filename=manage.py').group()
'projects/cprshelp/edit_file/'
>>> p = re.compile(r'projects/[\w ,\-<>]+/')>>> p.search('http://127.0.0.1:8300/projects/cprshelp/edit_file/?filename=manage.py').group()
'projects/cprshelp/'
>>>
```

also consider using `.get`:

```
filename = request.GET.get('filename','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your project/urls.py to

```
(r'^edit_file/$', views.edit_file),
```

Comment: In the valid urls, is there actually a space before 'edit_file/$'?

Comment: I changed ^projects/(?P<project_name>[\w ,-<>]+)/ to ^projects/(?P<project_name>\w+)/ and now it works

Comment: I think that the '-' should have been preceded with a backslash. Otherwise, you are defining a range between ',' and '<'.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'll give you an upvote for the right answer nonetheless.